# How to connect Node.js with Cassandra?

Tags: node.js, cassandra

I've been trying to connect Node.js with Cassandra on localhost for 50 years (feel like it), but haven't figured out how they work together. I would appreciate any suggestion that could lead to solution.

**Project Directory:**

```
project  - app - some files
        \- build - index.js, index.html, etc.(I start the server by "node index.js")
        \- node_modules - some modules
        \- signup - some files to be minified
        \- signin - some files to be minified
        \- apache-cassandra-3.0.6 - bin, conf, etc.(downloaded from tarball)
        \- package.json
        \- webpack.config.js
```

Webpack is working without any problem, so the problem doesn't exist in webpack configuration.
I can insert data using cqlsh, so the problem isn't the model of data structure.

I believe the problem is my lack of knowledge about how to use Node.js and  Cassandra together.

**My process to connect Node.js with Cassandra:**

1. go to build directory
2. `node index.js`
3. open localhost:3000 and find the home page, routed by express.js, displayed with no problem.
4. go to sign-up page and submit a form
5. error (no data inserted)

---

I'm not sure which contact point is correct, '127.0.0.1:9042' or '127.0.0.1'

```
var client = new cassandra.Client({contactPoints:['127.0.0.1:9042']});
                   OR
var client = new cassandra.Client({contactPoints:['127.0.0.1']});
```

I set my router like this.

```
var router = express.Router();
var insertUser = 'INSERT INTO keyspace.users (username, create_time, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);';

router.get"/", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html'); // This is working.
});

router.post("/signup", function(req, res) {
  var username = req.body.username;
  var email = req.body.email;
  var password = req.body.password;
  client.execute(insertUser, [username, now(), email, password], 
  { prepare: true }, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error"); // I receive error.
    } else {
      console.log("success");
    }
  });
});
```

Should I keep the cassandra running in the background like this?

`cd apache-cassandra-3.0.6` -> `cd bin` -> `./cassandra`

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is the error you are getting (can you log the 'err' instance when it occurs)?   Additionally, you do not need to provide the port as part of the contact points, you would provide it as protocolOptions { port: 9042}, i.e.:  new cassandra.Client({contactPoints:['127.0.0.1', protocolOptions { port: 9042 }}), but you don't need to do that here since 9042 is the default.

Comment: Server started
{ [Error: All host(s) tried for query failed. First host tried, 127.0.0.1:9042: AuthenticationError: Auth
entication provider not set. See innerErrors.]
  innerErrors:
   { '127.0.0.1:9042':
      { [AuthenticationError: Authentication provider not set]
        name: 'AuthenticationError',
        stack: 'Error: Authentication provider not set\n    at AuthenticationError.DriverError

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based the error message you provided, it looks like you have `PasswordAuthenticator` authentication or some other authenticator set up on your Cassandra instance.   Check your 'authenticator' property in your cassandra.yaml file, is it set to `PasswordAuthenticator`, `AllowAllAuthenticator`, or something else?

If using `PasswordAuthenticator`, you can specify credentials by passing a `PlainTextAuthenticator` instance to your client options as `authProvider`:

```
var PlainTextAuthProvider = cassandra.auth.PlainTextAuthProvider;
var client = new cassandra.Client({ contactPoints:['127.0.0.1:9042'], 
                                    authProvider: new PlainTextAuthProvider('cassandra', 'cassandra')};
```

The default user made available when using authentication is 'cassandra' with password 'cassandra', but you can change this by following [Configuring Authentication](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/security/security_config_native_authenticate_t.html).

Comment: Yes, I set authenticator to PasswordAuthenticator and authorizer to CassandraAuthorizer. This answer solved my problem, thank you!!

Comment: When I try to insert a user, I get an error saying "ReferenceError: now is not defined". I've set timeuuid to the column 'create_time'. Using cqlsh, I can insert a user by specifying now(). Do you have any idea?

Comment: now() isn't a function in javascript.  With the driver you can use: cassandra.types.TimeUuid.now()

Comment: It's working!! I can see the date inserted through my node.js application. Thank you so much!!